# ValueError: Tensor("ExponentialDecay_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

A Classifier for finding type of languge, Hindi or English.

```
ValueError: Tensor("ExponentialDecay_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor(("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/kernel/part_0:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)).
```

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
from absl import logging

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv("intern_test/data/english_text.csv",  encoding="latin-1")
df2 = pd.read_csv("intern_test/data/hinglish_text.csv",  encoding="latin-1")

df['label'] = 0 # English
df2['label'] = 1 # Hindi

df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])

df3.head()
# Training input on the whole training set with no limit on training epochs.
train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    df3, df3["label"], num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

# Prediction on the whole training set.
predict_train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    df3, df3["label"], shuffle=False)
# Prediction on the test set.
#predict_test_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
#    X_test, y_test, shuffle=False)

embedded_text_feature_column = hub.text_embedding_column(
    key="text", 
    module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")

optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(
    learning_rate=tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(
        global_step=0,
        learning_rate=0.1,
        decay_steps=10000,
        decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True))

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    hidden_units=[500, 100],
    feature_columns=[embedded_text_feature_column],
    n_classes=2,
    optimizer=optimizer
)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=5000);
```

Full traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-1c4563a14246> in <module>
      2 # batch size. This is roughly equivalent to 25 epochs since the training dataset
      3 # contains 25,000 examples.
----> 4 estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=5000);

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    356 
    357       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 358       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    359       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    360       return self

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1122       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1123     else:
-> 1124       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1125 
   1126   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1152       worker_hooks.extend(input_hooks)
   1153       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(
-> 1154           features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
   1155       global_step_tensor = training_util.get_global_step(g)
   1156       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1110 
   1111     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1112     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1113     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1114 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in _model_fn(features, labels, mode, config)
    520           input_layer_partitioner=input_layer_partitioner,
    521           config=config,
--> 522           batch_norm=batch_norm)
    523 
    524     super(DNNClassifier, self).__init__(

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in _dnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode, head, hidden_units, feature_columns, optimizer, activation_fn, dropout, input_layer_partitioner, config, use_tpu, batch_norm)
    300           labels=labels,
    301           optimizer=optimizer,
--> 302           logits=logits)
    303 
    304 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/head.py in create_estimator_spec(self, features, mode, logits, labels, optimizer, train_op_fn, regularization_losses)
    238           self._create_tpu_estimator_spec(
    239               features, mode, logits, labels, optimizer, train_op_fn,
--> 240               regularization_losses))
    241       return tpu_estimator_spec.as_estimator_spec()
    242     except NotImplementedError:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/head.py in _create_tpu_estimator_spec(self, features, mode, logits, labels, optimizer, train_op_fn, regularization_losses)
   1244         train_op = optimizer.minimize(
   1245             regularized_training_loss,
-> 1246             global_step=training_util.get_global_step())
   1247       elif train_op_fn is not None:
   1248         train_op = train_op_fn(regularized_training_loss)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
    411 
    412     return self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step,
--> 413                                 name=name)
    414 
    415   def compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list=None,

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, global_step, name)
    610           scope_name = var.op.name
    611         with ops.name_scope("update_" + scope_name), ops.colocate_with(var):
--> 612           update_ops.append(processor.update_op(self, grad))
    613       if global_step is None:
    614         apply_updates = self._finish(update_ops, name)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in update_op(self, optimizer, g)
    169       return optimizer._resource_apply_sparse_duplicate_indices(
    170           g.values, self._v, g.indices)
--> 171     update_op = optimizer._resource_apply_dense(g, self._v)
    172     if self._v.constraint is not None:
    173       with ops.control_dependencies([update_op]):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py in _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var)
    173         math_ops.cast(self._beta2_t, grad.dtype.base_dtype),
    174         math_ops.cast(self._epsilon_t, grad.dtype.base_dtype),
--> 175         grad, use_locking=self._use_locking)
    176 
    177   def _apply_sparse_shared(self, grad, var, indices, scatter_add):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gen_training_ops.py in resource_apply_adam(var, m, v, beta1_power, beta2_power, lr, beta1, beta2, epsilon, grad, use_locking, use_nesterov, name)
   1300                              beta2=beta2, epsilon=epsilon, grad=grad,
   1301                              use_locking=use_locking,
-> 1302                              use_nesterov=use_nesterov, name=name)
   1303   return _op
   1304   _result = None

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    348       # Need to flatten all the arguments into a list.
    349       # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 350       g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))
    351       # pylint: enable=protected-access
    352     except AssertionError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _get_graph_from_inputs(op_input_list, graph)
   5711         graph = graph_element.graph
   5712       elif original_graph_element is not None:
-> 5713         _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)
   5714       elif graph_element.graph is not graph:
   5715         raise ValueError("%s is not from the passed-in graph." % graph_element)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _assert_same_graph(original_item, item)
   5647   if original_item.graph is not item.graph:
   5648     raise ValueError("%s must be from the same graph as %s." % (item,
-> 5649                                                                 original_item))
   5650 
   5651
```

```
ValueError: Tensor("ExponentialDecay_4:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/kernel/part_0:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).
```

Comment: Try wrapping all your code within a `with tf.compat.v1.Graph().as_default():` context.

Comment: Still I am getting same error.

Comment: Hmm, I know the examples suggest using `tf.esimator` exactly as you are doing, but have you tried using a Keras optimizer, like [`tf.keras.optimizer.AdamOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam)? I'm actually kinda surprised they suggest you to use v1 optimizers with v2 estimators (maybe they work with [`tf.compat.v1.estimator.DNNClassifier`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/DNNClassifier))? Btw, what version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: I am using tensorflow version  1.13.1.

Comment: I have tried using keras optimizer using like ```tf.keras.optimizer.AdamOptimizer``` but it was giving errors, that's why I am using it this way.

Comment: Does it make any difference if I use it like this? Actually I had to use Adagrade but it was giving errors. The error was "The given object is not an Optimizer instance. Given: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.Adagrad object at 0x7f884b833d30>"

Comment: Can you suggest me how can I train model without errors.

Comment: Any other model?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were using TensorFlow 2.x. Unfortunately I don't really have too much experience with `tf.estimator`, but what you are doing looks like it should work. You could use a Keras with an embedding layer and some dense layers (as show e.g. [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/2)), but `tf.estimator` should work...

Comment: Now, what can I do for correcting tf.estimator approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving exponential decay using function, which takes learning rate and steps as input and use it as an input for keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler.

Here is an example for using exponential decay.

```
def exponential_decay_fn(epoch):
    return 0.01 * 0.1**(epoch / 20) 

def exponential_decay(lr0, s):
    def exponential_decay_fn(epoch):
        return lr0 * 0.1**(epoch / s)
    return exponential_decay_fn

exponential_decay_fn = exponential_decay(lr0=0.01, s=20)  

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="nadam", metrics=["accuracy"])
n_epochs = 25  


lr_scheduler = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(exponential_decay_fn)
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=n_epochs,
                    validation_data=(X_valid_scaled, y_valid),
                    callbacks=[lr_scheduler])
```

I hope this answeres your question.